# How to properly setup the barryvdh/laravel-cors in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, facebook, cors, axios

I am currently new in ReactJS and facing problem regarding getting the response of API the console log shows of error of this

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

they recommend to me that I use the `barryvdh/laravel-cors` to allow the cors in my API. I will show you guys my front-end code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json',{
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
}
```

In my logs, I will share here the captured image.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it is needed here, but do you have this in your HEAD? <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: The question is incorrect, neither Laravel or barryvdh/laravel-cors has anything to do with your frontend and facebook api.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your **Axios** request itself, if you clearly see

```
axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json',{})
```

You've an additional parameter, While you are not passing any headers or other parameters, if you remove the `{}` then it should work.

```
axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
```

And if you see the results of your `console` you can see on where it clearly states that OPTIONS request is throwing a **405** status code,

from MDN

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response
>   status code indicates that the request method is known by the server
>   but is not supported by the target resource.

You'll need to directly access the resource, probably your axios is generating `Pre Flight Request with OPTIONS header` due to `{}`, which is being rejected by the resource itself.

You can also try doing it with a simple fetch request,

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.json())
  })
```

Comment: Nothing to do with fetch and axios. It's an issue of CORS.

Comment: @KashyapMerai Sorry, its not the cors issue, as the resource is available at public domain and can be accessed from any client and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set to wildcard. https://imgur.com/a/Ytsi07V see it for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

CORS is controlled by backend API and in your case, you don't have control over it which is
`https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json`.

Browser prevents your code from accessing the response because of the browser can't see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response.

Things can still get working by making the request through a Proxy can where a proxy sends appropriate CORS header on behalf of your request.

```js
const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"; 
fetch(proxy + url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(contents => console.log(contents))
  .catch(() => console.log("CORS Error" + url ))
```

Making a request through a proxy will work this way

1. CORS proxy will forward your request to `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json`
2. Return response from `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.
3. Now your browser can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers present in the response header.

For more detail explanation you can check out this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/2850383

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present in the response and is set to all.